# XML import of IndexCat files

Tags: filemaker, nlm

the National Library of Medicine (NLM) has made available to the public last April its Index Medicus collection.  This collection is composed of 5 series, each series containing several volumes.  These files are available as XML files at this website: http://www.nlm.nih.gov/hmd/indexcat/indexcatxml.html
The same website also has a file for the Document Type Definition (DTD).
I am trying to import these XML files into FileMaker Pro 12 Advanced, but so have been unsuccessful.  I realize I need to specify a XSLT style sheet that transforms the XML into the proper grammar.  I do not know how to do that.  I used the example that comes with FileMaker (called msdso_elem.xslt). I also modified the top of one the XML files as indicated below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fmresultset PUBLIC "-//FMI//DTD fmresultset//EN"
"http://www.nlm.nih.gov/databases/dtd/nlmindexcataloguerecordset_130401.dtd">
```

With these two modifications, I am able to import all records in a series, but the fields do not correspond to the original fields of the XML file.  In particular, I have fewer fields in the newly created FileMaker file, and the information they contain is not well separated (for example the author first name is smashed to the author last name, rather than being in its own field).

Can anybody help me to modify the XSLT style sheet to achieve a proper import of the NLM XML files?

Many thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You can try the universal XSLT at http://jensteich.de/fmfaq/export/universal-xslt-fur-den-import-beliebiger-xml-daten/